# Reactjs conditional Rendering issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I'm having issues with rendering some react componenets based on whether a variable has a value or not, it seems to just not render at all no matter whether !user or user is used
redux seems to be working fine where it is either null or has a value but when the state changes between null and a value I still don't see either icon nthat is meant to be rendering

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Menu} from 'antd';
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
import {
    MailOutlined, AppstoreOutlined,
    SettingOutlined, ShoppingOutlined,
    ShoppingCartOutlined, UserAddOutlined,
    UserOutlined, LogoutOutlined
} from '@ant-design/icons';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import firebase from "firebase";

const {SubMenu, Item} = Menu;

const Header = () => {
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState("home");
    let dispatch = useDispatch()
    let user = useSelector((state) => ({...state}))
    let history = useHistory();
    console.log(user)
    const logout = () => {
        firebase.auth().signOut();
        dispatch({
            type: "logOff",
            payload: null,
        });
        history.push("/login");
    };
    const handleClick = (e) => {
        // console.log(e.key); this handles the click event for each button clicked, e is the current event of click
        setCurrent(e.key); // this sets the current button clicked, if home is clicked then css shows the on clicked design
    };

    return (

        <Menu onClick={handleClick} selectedKeys={[current]} mode="horizontal">

            <Item key="home" icon={<AppstoreOutlined/>}>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </Item>
            {!user && (
                <Item key="register" icon={<UserAddOutlined/>} className="float-right">
                    <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
                </Item>
            )}
            {!user && (
                <Item key="login" icon={<UserOutlined/>} className="float-right">
                    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
                </Item>
            )}
            {user && (
                <SubMenu>
                    {user && user.role === "admin" && (
                        <Item>
                            <Link to="/admin/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                        </Item>
                    )}
                    {user && user.role === "user" && (
                        <Item>
                            <Link to="/user/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                        </Item>
                    )}
                    <Item icon={<LogoutOutlined/>} onClick={logout}>
                        Logout
                    </Item>
                </SubMenu>
            )}
        </Menu>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Please add the code in your question even if you can't get it to format properly.  Someone will likely help by editing your question to fix the formatting.

Comment: ah ok thank youu I'll do that now

Comment: please share [mwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self-contained%20correct%20example.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah I believe the problem was that on the useSelector line i did not wrap the user variable with {}. The bug was found here:

```
let user = useSelector((state) => ({...state}));
```

The fix was too add {} to the user variable like this

```
let {user} = useSelector((state) => ({...state}));
```